# How to create the rewrite rule for the url where the parameter/arguments will contain the dynamic value?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

I have a rwrite rule which is like this:

```
RewriteRule ^30/edit-print-ready-vinyl-banners.html edit_print_ready_form.php?id=30
```

Now I need a Rewrite rule such that if i append the dynamic parameter say "pro_id" and "osCsid" to it
likewise

```
edit_print_ready_form.php?id=30&pro_id=51&osCsid=hdsfjhfkjhk11212jhkjkjhkjh
```

Now if i use the rewrite rule I have mentioned at the top, I do not get the "`$_GET['pro_id']`" and "`$_GET['osCsid']`" on the page i am redirected to..

please guide me to write a rewrite rule to have it for dynamic parameters appended to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the *QSA* flag for that rule to have the original query automatically appended to the new one:

```
RewriteRule ^30/edit-print-ready-vinyl-banners.html edit_print_ready_form.php?id=30 [QSA]
```

Comment: Please elaborate, i am new to htaccess